# Сортировка по лайкам

Tags: javascript, c#, алгоритм

Мне нужно сортировать контент только по лайкам. Необходимо как-то оценивать, что пост новый, и если он набрал n лайков за короткое время - он взлетает в топ.

Мне нужен легкий аналог сортировки в **play market** по скачиваниям (только в данном случае по `like`).

Comment: Раз нужно - сортируйте!

Comment: все просто. koef = countLike / (врямя в часах/днях сколько уже висит контент). нужно експеремминтировать.

Answer (score 1):

Аналогию ищите [здесь](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/355/quarter/ru-stackoverflow/2016-01-01/194380#194380) - среди недельных, месячных, квартальных топов и топов за всё время. Каждый счётчик сбрасывается в начале периода. Кроме того, нужно хранить время существования поста.